# Excel - Formulas that total across multiple sheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to make a spreadsheet to handle my monthly budgets. I have very little experience in Excel 2011 and I know there are pre-made templates already but what I need is very small in comparison.

I would like to have one file for each year, with 12 sheets within that represent each month. I want to have it keep a running total of YTD income on every month as well as other running totals. Is this possible to have a formula that keeps a running total across a variable number of sheets? I would want to be able to create a new sheet (month) and have it automatically have the previous total populated and update when I input the month's amount.

Comment: You'll need to look into Excel macros if you're going to be varying the number of sheets, or at least updating the formulas manually at the start of each month.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you create four sheets, for example:

Totals, Jan, Feb, End

and you want your summary stats to be located on the Totals tab, you can create all your formulas as follows. In a cell on the Totals tab enter:

```
=sum(Jan:End!A1)
```

This formula will add up all the values in A1 from each sheet between Jan and End. If you insert a new sheet between Feb and End, say Mar, then your totals will update automatically.

I would probably just create all 12 months in advance, but this is another option for you.

Answer (score 2):

What about creating all of the monthly sheets first and then creating the formula? Is there any reason why you need to wait for the month to begin to create the worksheet?

If so, the 2nd tip on this link may help - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/5-tips-for-working-with-multiple-worksheets-in-excel-HA001042919.aspx.